# How to center a graphic inside a framed cell without using another cell

Tags: notebooks, formatting, cells, alignment

Below is a gif of the situation I am having.

First, notice I am working inside a framed cell.  Within this cell I placed two graphics.  The first (on top) is left aligned.  The second, is centered.  However, using the center justification in the formatting tools does not work.  So I created another cell within the framed cell and then centered inside that cell.

There are a couple problems with this method.  First, the cell becomes highlighted whenever I rotate the graphic.  This is an eye sore.  Second, because this is a cell it takes on the characteristics of inline cells, which I don't always want depending on what I am centering.

I'd like to center the object without creating a cell inside the framed cell.  Can you think of an easy way to do this?  I'd like to avoid creating a separate style in the stylesheets because I don't always know ahead of time whether the cell will have a centered item.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Look at `Pane`. It supports explicit sizing and centering. Also you can turn off that background highlighting for cells or styles.

Comment: I see.  The cell was created using the "Frame" button in the Writing Assistant Palette.  It's just a cell property.

Comment: Yeah I know how that goes. One thing you can do is to set `Background -> None` for the style `"InlineCellEditing"`. That'll hide the background for you for all inline cells in the notebook. I think it's possible on a cell-by-cell basis though. Let me look into that.

Comment: I'm now not sure if it's possible on a cell-by-cell basis. You can change inline cell styles, but the editing style may always be the same.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok I think I'll try messing around with Pane.  I haven't spent much time with that yet.   The solution of changing the options for "inline cell" within this framed cell won't work for me, because I still may need to use an inline cell of the previous option type somewhere else within the framed cell.

Comment: I didn't give a thorough look at it, so I would also give a look at what you can do by playing with those sorts of styles. Look at ``FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["Core.nb", "StyleSheetPath"]`` and see what you can dredge up. You can hopefully change the inline editing style for a specific inline cell style and so you could embed a cell of a different style. Alternatively make that cell deployed. You can still rotate the graphic but can't enter it, so the editing thing shouldn't show up.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain, You can create a `GraphicsRow` with 3 elements, where the first will be aligned left, the second - centered and the last one will be empty. Is it appropriate?

Comment: @Rom38 - Sorry the delay... start of the semester.. super busy.  GraphicsRow is a good idea, but I'm thinking Pane might be better.  I don't see the advantage to using GraphicsRow.  It seems more messy.  But I will check it out and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: Also I probably should have added that the object I want centered doesn’t need to be an graphic.  I could also be text.  In general the problem is how justify part of a cell to the left and another part of the same cell to the Center.  I can’t seem to find a clean way to do this without messing with inline cells.  I want to avoid this.   I’ll give Pane a try.  Other ideas are welcome.  : )